# How to make toString function for multiple data?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I don't know why mongo mlab _id is not a string? I need to double check context and the viewer._id in my schema. This is my code:

```
resolve: async ({_id}, {status, ...args}, context) => {
        // {_id} destructure _id property on root
        console.log("allTodosByUser field = ",_id)
        console.log("allTodosByUser field = ",context.user._id)
        console.log("allTodosByUser equal",Boolean(_id.toString() === context.user._id.toString())) // suddenly using toString becomes true
```

This is not really a big deal but somehow I don't want to use toString for comparison:

```
if(_id.toString() === context.user._id.toString())
```

So I want to make a function maybe like this:

```
const { _id, context.user._id: contextUserId } = [_id, context.user._id], // push the _id, and context.user._id in an object so I can destructure?
```

Comment: Does `if(_id === context.user._id)` not work?

Comment: The question is why would the `_id` be a string? Generally it's an object in Mongo, not a string, and that ObjectID has a `toString` method

Comment: @SumnerEvans yes, it's not working but using toString works

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Comment: @adeneo I want to compare the graphql context and root viewer...

Comment: I don't really know what `graphql` or `context` is, but if it's coming from a Mongo DB and has a `_id` property, that property is as explained in the documentation above, an ObjectID, and as two objects are never the same, you probably *have* to use `toString` to do the comparison.

Comment: JavaScript equality operators compares non-primitives (everything but boolean, number, string, symbol, and undefined) based on *reference*, not *value*: `[1,2,3] !== [1,2,3]`. However `[1,2,3].toString() === [1,2,3].toString()` because strings *are* compared on value.

Comment: was using mongoose, thanks for the docs link

Comment: Mongoose has a method for this, `first._id.equals( second._id )`

Comment: @adeneo Technically speaking "mongoose does not" and it's [just an import](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/types/objectid.js) of a method implemented in the [basic node driver interface](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/ObjectID.html#equals) which is actually [implemented in this code](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/1.0-branch/lib/bson/objectid.js#L206) which somehow strangely implements a concept that might have been repeated in the obvious here a few times.